# Make a smooth density plot on the globe

Tags: python, graphics, plot, octave

I have a set of data which has the following format

```
city1 state1 country1 frequency1
city2 state2 country2 frequency2
city3 state3 country3 frequency3
...
cityN stateN countryN frequencyN
```

I need to create a smooth density plot on the globe. Anybody has this kind of experience, for example in `python` or `octave` or other computational packages?

Answer (score 0):

My solution introduces smoothness by averaging the frequency over Earth areas close to the definition points (cities).

1. Make a rectangular equidistant mesh on [the cylindrical projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Cylindrical) of the globe. Mesh should have sufficient number of cells to differentiate different regions by their frequency. Also the mesh should not be too dense - or you will obtain the same function as in the input.
2. Collect frequencies according to cells their cities are placed in and calculate mean frequency for each cell.
3. Associate center points of the cells with the averaged frequencies you obtained.
4. Draw a 3D plot of the obtained table-defined function. Octave should do this.